# Issue with a night sky rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I have been trying to render a starry night animation with blender. While the stars look fine when rendered in a single frame, but when they are in a sequence, some of the stars appear to flicker in and out of existence randomly. I have tried two different ways of rendering stars, the first using an emission texture and the second with a particle system of emitting objects. https://giphy.com/gifs/7epE5LW1ChYqc is the video file of what they appear like, and some stars seem to wink in and out of existence between each frame. I don't know what is causing this, or if there is a way for me to remedy this.

Comment: How many samples are you using?

Comment: For the cycles I used 1000 and still found the same thing occured. This gif is from blender render.